# how to use regex to identify specific endings?

Tags: regex, text

How to use regex to match company names ending with pty or pty ltd (there could be comma, blank and period in between) or inc, with or without comma in front/period at the end such as inc/inc./, Inc., and case insensitive? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't mean to steal anyone's credit but Daniel Ignat who answered first in my opinion got it almost right this is a revised version that in my opinion is more appropriate:

`/\w* (inc|pty((\.|,)? ltd))(\.|,)?/ig`

Also this assumes that company name is made up of only one word Ex. "Google Inc"

Also it would be helpfull to know what where are you using this regex details will vary from Perl, JavaScript, VBA, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a starting point built with the help of [Regexper.com](http://www.regexper.com/#((pty%7Cpty%20ltd)%7C(I%7Ci)nc(%5C.%7C%2C%7C%20))%24)

```
((pty|pty ltd)|(I|i)nc(\.|,| ))$
```